# query to find out count of rows in a particular instance of time

Tags: timesten

Is it possible to find out the count of rows in all tables at a particular instance of time (not depends on any column values)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select sum(num_rows) 
from user_tables;
```

user_tables is a timesten table with useful information about the tables in the schema.  It has a num_rows attribute that will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't, edited your answer to format your code. I am guessing that the downvote came from someone who wanted an explanation on the code.